# GMPL generic way to produce params

Tags: linear-programming, glpk

Hello is there a way to generate params in GMPL as example io have a funcion 
min:c[i]*x[i] and constrains that looks like A[i][j]*x[i]=b[i]. Where A[i][j]=1/(i+j-1) and i,j=1,2....,n. c[i]=b[i]=sum(j=1,...,n)1/(i+j-1) where i=1,...,n.
So there is a question is there a way to generate matrix A from equation? or do i need to make this matrix manual in data section ? and one more question is there a good way to find (n) maximum size of this problem when with precision of 2 numbers without modifying objective function ?

Comment: By "precision of 2 numbers", do you mean "double precision"?

Comment: i mean that the error between exact value and calculated value is less than 0.01

Comment: Ah, okay. That would be "two decimal places" (if the difference is calculated as abs (x-y) < 0.01) or "two significant figures (if calculated as abs(x/y - 1) < 0.01).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
param n := 3;
set I := 1..n;

param A{i in I, j in I} := 1/(i+j-1); 
param c{i in I} := sum{j in I} 1/(i+j-1);
# or better (may be):
# param c{i in I} := sum{j in I} A[i,j];
display A,c;

end;
```

The output should look like:

```
Reading model section from x.mod...
9 lines were read
Display statement at line 8
A[1,1] = 1
A[1,2] = 0.5
A[1,3] = 0.333333333333333
A[2,1] = 0.5
A[2,2] = 0.333333333333333
A[2,3] = 0.25
A[3,1] = 0.333333333333333
A[3,2] = 0.25
A[3,3] = 0.2
c[1] = 1.83333333333333
c[2] = 1.08333333333333
c[3] = 0.783333333333333
```

GMPL is a subset of AMPL. You may want to read the AMPL book to understand more about the syntax.

I am afraid I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Is it possible to use that's version od params on data section?

Comment: The data section can only contain data, no expressions.